# Jquery: FAQ Style

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<table class="site">
<tr>
    <td>
        <span style="float: right;" class='show'>Show More</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="site_info">
   <td><%= site.id %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align='right'>
More
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Anytime someone clicks ".show", I want it to display ".site_info" (hidden on startup). I've tried many things, including:

```
$('.site_info').hide().css('cursor', 'pointer');
$('.show').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.site_info').slideToggle();
});
```

I just can't seem to be able to find/select the site_info portion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.site_info').hide().css('cursor', 'pointer');
$('.show').click(function() {
    $(this).parents( "table" ).find('.site_info').show( "slideToggle" );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `find` command only searches descendents of the current element.

try this..

```
$(this).parents("table").find(".site-info").slideToggle();
```

Comment: `find` searches "descendants", not to be confused with `children`.

Comment: Should also use `closest` instead of `parents`, in case there are nested tables (though hopefully there aren't).

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".site_info").hide().css("cursor", "pointer");
$(".show").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("table.site").find("tr.site_info").slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.site_info').hide().css('cursor', 'pointer');
$('.show').click(function() {
    $('.site_info').show("slow");
});
```